# how to unlock a PDF file extracted from an iPhone app?

Tags: pdf, locking

I've downloaded the Cosmopolitan magazine on my iPhone not so long ago and from there I purchased the Sept. 2014 issue of the magazine. However, I can't save or e-mail my purchased issue from the app, all I can do is screen-cap it but that wouldn't give me a quality good enough to read the small text on the pages. So I eventually googled it and ended up downloading iFunBox which gives you the contents of your iPhone applications. From there, I looked up the content folders of the Cosmopolitan app and ended up with a PDF file which I'm assuming is the Sept. 2014 issue, which is cool, but the problem is that it's locked :(

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with unlocking the said PDF file?
Here's the PDF file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Tf7C_JNaZgeUJOa0NqYjB6Vkk/view
and here's the Cosmopolitan app contents folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Tf7C_JNaZgVE54dWZyaUpYazA/view?usp=sharing (the p/w might be somewhere in the files there but I failed to find, OTL)

Comment: I think what you are asking for is illegal even though you paid for that issue of the magazine and should have every right to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a password removing utility.  Here are 7 I found when googling for "pdf password removal"

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/pdf-password-remover.htm